# Como substituir seguindo um padrao pre-determinado python

Tags: python, number-format, generators

dentro de txt tenho

```
12480 = B X
43200 = B X
47040 = B X
50880 = B X
54720 = B X
58560 = B X
62400 = B X
66240 = B X
70080 = B X
73920 = B X
77760 = B X
85440 = B X
89280 = B X
93130 = B X
96960 = B X
```

quero substituir "X" por padrões numéricos que imagino eu que deva ser colocado em uma lista

por exeplo:

```
listaZ = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

listaY = [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

usando a "listaZ" fica assim

```
12480 = B 0
43200 = B 1
47040 = B 2
50880 = B 3
54720 = B 4
58560 = B 0
62400 = B 1
66240 = B 2
70080 = B 3
73920 = B 4
77760 = B 0
85440 = B 1
89280 = B 2
93130 = B 3
96960 = B 4
```

usando a "listaY" ficaria assim

```
12480 = B 0
43200 = B 1
47040 = B 0
50880 = B 2
54720 = B 0
58560 = B 3
62400 = B 0
66240 = B 4
70080 = B 0
73920 = B 1
77760 = B 0
85440 = B 2
89280 = B 0
93130 = B 3
96960 = B 0
```

eu fiz esse codigo aqui mas eu fiz ele gerar numeros randomicos e isso nao me serviu bem por isso preciso que siga um padrao pre-determinado, alguem tem ideia de como colocar isso em pratica?

```
import random
import fileinput

file_name = 'C:/Users/Felipe/Desktop/GH.txt'

c3 = (random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1):
    if 'X' in line:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.replace('X',str (random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])),1)

    print (line)
```

Comment: Não será mais fácil você descrever exatamente o que precisa fazer? Por mais interessante que seja você tentar criar a solução sozinho e buscar implementá-la, pode ser que você fique preso naquilo que chamamos de problema XY, onde você tenta implementar uma solução que não é exatamente a solução que precisa, algo como tentar construir um tanque de guerra para matar uma formiga; fará o trabalho, mas precisa de todo esse esforço? Já é, no mínimo, a terceira pergunta que cria para esse problema, isso pode ser um indício que está tentando projetar o tanque de guerra.

Comment: Hahahahha eu so faco pergunta mesmo quando nao tem outro jeito, eu consegui completar o objetivo que era fazer gerar números aleatórios eu achei que iria funcionar bem mas não funcionou esses números estranhos geram arquivos midi

Answer (score 2):

Você pode simplesmente criar um indice para percorrer a lista desejada dentro do "for" e zerar ela quando atingir o tamanho da lista, reiniciando a lista, exemplo:

```
import fileinput

file_name = 'GH.txt'

listaZ = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
listaY = [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]

lista = listaY  # selecione a lista desejada

i = 0

for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1):
    if 'X' in line:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.replace('X',str( lista[i] ),1)

        i = i + 1 # incrementa o indice

        if i == len(lista):  # zera se atingir o tamanho da lista
            i = 0

        print (line)
```

Comment: Cleyton, por favor elabora sua resposta, informe o que você fez de diferente da pergunta e onde a pessoa "errou". "fácil" não é uma resposta válida

Comment: Editado, melhorou?

Comment: Cleyton deu certinho, de primeira deu um erro do carai por causa dessa parte file_name = 'GH.txt'   o pycharm não achou o arquivo ai eu só coloquei certo e pegou beleza agradeço a todos

Comment: Ok Felipe, vote em sua melhor resposta para ajudar a comunidade. Abraço e boa sorte!